# Russell's paradox and axiom of separation

Tags: set-theory, axioms, paradoxes

I don't quite understand how the axiom of separation resolves Russell's paradox in an entirely satisfactory way (without relying on other axioms).

I see that it removes the immediate contradiction that is produced by unrestricted comprehension, but it seems that we still need further axioms to guarantee that a well-formed set $S$ will never contain the set of all given elements (of $S$) which do not contain themselves.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It might not be the best formatted or put question ever, but surely it is a lot better than a lot of questions by new users we see here...

Comment: One approach I have found that may be useful is to not postulate a priori the existence of *any* actual sets in your set theory -- not the empty set and not some amorphous infinite set as in ZFC. In this way, you will not be able to prove the existence of *any* set, but you can prove that certain sets, e.g the Russell set do not exist. As Hurkyl pointed out, a set does not exist if postulating its existence leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @Dan:  That's an insightful way to look at it.  I like that, but I think I come to the same stumbling block when I want to introduce the Axiom of Separation.  Can you explain why we know that there is no contradiction for the Russell Set, no matter the other axioms?

Comment: @af3 As I see it, there are just two kinds of axioms in any set theory: Those that postulate a prior that existence of certain sets, e.g. the empty set. And those that can be used to infer the existence of one or more sets assuming the existence of others, e.g. if $S$ is a set, then there exists another set, the so-called power set of $S$. If your axioms are only of the latter kind, you cannot actually prove the existence of any set -- not the Russell Set or any other. I'm no expert, but as far as I can tell, the latter kind of axiom is all you really need to develop most, if not all of math.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I see what you're saying.  As I understand it, though, one of the main points of set theory was to put mathematics on a foundation where actually have an answer to the question of "what is a number?" Therefore, you would never use only the type of axioms that you are talking about, but I can see how it's a useful way to think about things.

Comment: @AF3 Nothing is to stop you from postulating, say, Peano's Axioms *outside* of your set theory, just as you might postulate the existence of any algebraic structure. This approach has the advantage of constructing a kind of firewall between number theory and set theory. If Peano's axioms turn out to be inconsistent -- as far fetched as that may seem -- they would simply not be true and your set theory would remain intact.

Comment: The "problem" with that would be that all of the things in the Peano axioms can be expressed in the more primitive notions of ZFC (as I understand it).  I can see the appeal of what you're saying, though.

Comment: @AF3 These "primitive notions of ZFC" as you put it are based on a priori assumptions about the existence of a certain infinite set (or the empty set depending on who you talk to). I am not convinced that you need to make such assumptions to develop, say, number theory.

Comment: I'm only using the primitive relation of "membership" and the definition of "set" that relies on a "set" either having a member of being equal to the empty set.  This seems like the strongest way to develop the concept of "number", doesn't it?

Comment: @AF3  I believe you need the Axiom of Infinity to construct the set of natural numbers in ZFC theory. You may also have to assume the existence of an empty set.

Answer (score 3):

The guarantee that such a set can't exist is already given by the argument of Russell's paradox: its existence leads to a contradiction therefore it can't exist.

The problem with unrestricted comprehension was that it guaranteed the set does exist, which causes a problem because of the conflicting guarantees.

Comment: Well, that's not the complete answer. The complete answer is as Andres said in his comment: no, we don't need any other axioms. This is because of the inherent contradiction in the definition of the set in Russel's paradox.

Comment: Hurkyl: 

Your first sentence is certainly true, but it doesn't show that such a set will not exist within a given theory, it shows that it it will not exist within any theory that obeys the classical laws of thought.

Comment: @AF3: what does that even mean?

Comment: Editing: One Sec

Comment: tomasz:  Thanks for the answer.  The reason I don't see why this has such a simple answer is because it seems like you still need to make sure that the "Russell Set" is still not a part of any larger set, though.  If that was the case, then it seems that we would have the same contradiction.  I certainly believe that I'm incorrect here, but I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @AF3: The argument of Russell's paradox is a *proof* that the Russell set doesn't exist (if it exists, then it is either a member of itself or it is not, and both cases lead to contradiction, therefore it doesn't exist); this is true even when applied to Cantor's set theory that has unrestricted comprehension. Despite that, it is indeed potentially possible that ZFC proves the Russell set exists; this happens if and only if ZFC is inconsistent. So far, we do not yet have any argument that shows ZFC is inconsistent.

Comment: @Hurkyl:  I was saying that it is a proof that the Russell Set does not exist in any system which obeys the Law of the Excluded Middle and the Law of Non-Contradiction.  Obviously, it does "exist" in Cantor's theory.  Ultimately, we come to the same point.  What prevents the paradox from happening, though, if we do not know that, given a set S, the subset of all elements of S which are not members of themselves, is not itself a member of S?  If we have this then don't we have the same problem?

Comment: You can prove it doesn't exist in Cantor's theory as well. It's inconsistent, so we expect to be able both to prove and disprove any claim. Anyways, in ZFC, you can prove that unless ZFC is inconsistent, ZFC cannot prove ZFC is consistent. So if you want an actual proof of consistency, you're going to have to suggest some other system in which such a proof is to be carried out.

Comment: In fact, I think (but am not really sure) there's an odd pseudoparadox here: I think that it is possible for ZFC to be consistent, yet for ZFC to be able to prove ZFC is inconsistent. (if I'm correct, this bears some relation to Skolem's paradox, and to nonstandard models and stuff)

Comment: No you're wrong. If ZFC is consistent, ZFC cannot prove that it (suitably encoded) is inconsistent otherwise ZFC itself would really be inconsistent. Skolem's paradox and nonstandard models have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the axiom scheme of separation "resolves" Russell's paradox at all, but restricts the way of using predicates to determine sets.

The paradox is nothing but a proof that there is no one-to-one correspondence between predicates and classes: there are predicates that not defines a class. When writing sets as $\{x|p(x)\}$ that one-to-one correspondence is understood. Therefore axiomatic set theory is to show that sets exists and show rules how to create sets. If $A$ is a set, then the set $\{x\in A|p(x)\}$ never will cause any trouble, due to the theories.

Comment: This is making more sense, but I still don't understand why the Russell Construction occurring as a subset does not cause problems. Is it because once you have this restriction, then when you consider the Russell Construction as a subset, you just end up with a "proof" by contradiction that the subset must actually be outside of your set, and therefore it does not exist inside your reference set?  If that's the case, then why do we need the Axiom of Regularity?

Comment: I see where I'm getting it wrong (I think).  We just have that if B is the set formed by taking all of elements of A who are not members of themselves, then B is not in A.  There is no contradiction, it's just a proof (that B is not in A).

Comment: $\{x\in A|x\notin x\}$ is not a paradox at all, it is just an exclusion of all the $x\in A$ that belongs to itself, if that even is possible..

Answer (score 0):

Axioms are used to show that under some circumstances, some sets exist.

Russell's paradox shows that not every definable collection can be a set. So we have to restrict what sort of definable collections we allow. The separation axiom schema essentially say that if $A$ is already a set, then every definable subcollection of $A$ is also a set.

If we repeat the Russell paradox over a set $A$ using Separation, then we don't get a contradiction. We get an interesting theorem:

> For every set $A$ there is a set $B$ such that $B\notin A$.

Comment: I actually just figured out the last part right before you wrote it.  Let me just recap to make sure:  We argue this theorem by the same reasoning as Russell's Paradox, but that doesn't mean that we have an inherent contradiction in our theory, because we're now safely insulated.  In that way, the Axiom Schema of Separation does actually resolve that specific  paradox.

Comment: @AF3 But you also need some way to be sure that it is impossible to construct the Russell Set using the axioms of ZFC. Perhaps Asaf can explain how this is accomplished?

Comment: I think you still have the Russell Set, it just doesn't produce a contradiction.  Edit:  I agree with Lehr.  I was abusing the term "Russell Set".

Comment: @Dan Christensen: but there are no "Russell-sets", the paradox prove that. And if you mean the axiom of foundation, it doesn't show nothing of the kind, it just trying to avoid something that scares somebody.

Comment: @AF3 If you can prove the existence of the Russell Set, your set theory blows up in self-contradiction. You must be sure that this cannot happen.

Comment: Right, I was abusing the term.  I agree with what Lehr is saying.  It makes much more sense now.

Comment: The ZFC Axiom of Separation replaced the axiom of unrestricted comprehension that allowed the construction of the Russell Set in naive set theory. It closed one door, but how can we be sure that it is not possible to prove the existence of the Russell Set by other means using the axioms of ZFC?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Russell's Paradox exposed the inconsistency of a proposed formal set theory of his day. This so-called *naive* set theory allowed you to derive theorems of the form:

> $\exists S: \forall a:[a \in S \iff P(a)]$ for *any* unary predicate $P$.

This was called the axiom schema of *unrestricted* comprehension.

For $P(a)\equiv a\notin a$, however, we could then prove to the contrary that:

$\neg\exists S:\forall a:[a\in S \iff a\notin a]$

The moral of the story: Just because you can "define" a set doesn't mean it actually exists. Some *restrictions* must apply.

These restrictions were described, at least in part, in the so-called axiom schema of *restricted* comprehension that replaced the above axiom:

> $\forall X:\exists S: \forall a:[a \in S \iff a\in X \land P(a)]$ for *any* unary predicate $P$ where $S$ is not referred to in $P(a)$.

This eliminated the direct route to Russell's Paradox and plugged one hole in naive set theory. Various ways including effectively banning self-reference altogether (e.g. $x\in x$) were also introduced into set theory. This, it was hoped, would banish anything resembling Russell's Paradox for good.